# Task Scheduler cannot run application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a C#.net 2.0 Console Application in Visual Studio 2012. It fetches currency and save data to MS Access successfully. But when I try to run it by Task Scheduler it doesnt run.

Although application completes codes in 3-4 seconds normally, when I had run it in Task Scheduler it seems Running and never completes anything.

It gives these errors in event logs:

```
Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=130990590017921570
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=130990590019310981
ReportIdentifier=a099e48c-cb32-11e5-bf25-001f298d0a8f
WOW64=1
Response.BucketId=dbb55061274ff83bb427ed5f7309e3ba
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=129010695092
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name= Problem Signature  01
Sig[0].Value=wp2access.exe
Sig[1].Name= Problem Signature  02
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name= Problem Signature  03
Sig[2].Value=56b332fb
Sig[3].Name= Problem Signature  04
Sig[3].Value=System.Data
Sig[4].Name= Problem Signature  05
Sig[4].Value=2.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name= Problem Signature  06
Sig[5].Value=537ea536
Sig[6].Name= Problem Signature  07
Sig[6].Value=1e6d
Sig[7].Name= Problem Signature  08
Sig[7].Value=85
Sig[8].Name= Problem Signature  09
Sig[8].Value=System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
```

I tried

1. to move application to upper folders(D:\Services\ etc.)
2. gaved full permissions for (Users, NETWORKS Service, NETWORK) to app.exe and db.mdb and its folder
3. gaved full permissions to C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp
4. marked copy local for references (System, System.Data, System.XML) and copied them in application folder
5. Changed .net framework version from 2.0 to 3.0, 3.5, 4.0
6. Tried in Windows Server 2012 also. (Runs successfully by double clicking in GUI, but not in Task Scheduler)
7. Changed user Account in Task Scheduler (My Personel Account, SYSTEM etc.)

But nothing changed. I can not solve why application runs successfuly with double click in GUI, but not by Task Scheduler.

Any help on solving this would really be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use Process Monitor to look for failure events

Comment: You're getting an exception on the OleDB provider, are you sure the provider is well configured and the configuration of the application is the same when it runs with the task scheduler? maybe you're using a configuration file in your local folder? if that's the case it's possible the execution path is not the same as the path where the executable is stored

Comment: Yes it is same configuration. I located app.exe and db.mdb in D:\Services and when I double click D:\Services\app.exe it works normally. But in Task Scheduler it doesnt work. I also changed connectionstring from "Data Source=vt.mdb" to "Data Source=D:\services\vt.mdb" but nothing changed

Comment: Did you set the " Start in" value to "D:\Services" as part of the action? If not, try that.

Comment: @Mark, yes I tried now; nothing changed

Comment: After moving files to C:\ root directory it gaved some details: location: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()   It can not open access database, but why

Comment: Are you using any environment variable in your application like "CURRENT_DIRECTORY"? I had deployed an application on client which starts with user login. Application runs perfect when we manually start them but when Task scheduler or Windows startup starts it, its "CURRENT_DIRECTORY" was set by default "C:\Windows\System32".

Comment: It is solved strangely. Application query database in a loop. I added this code before query.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
Then it worked succesfully by Task Scheduler. Maybe opening/closing connection rapidly occurs problem. Thanks very much